# Is it possible to bind gridview with multiple table data at design time

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can i bind multiple table data to grid view while in design mode.

This is my design

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grdACH" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White"
            BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black"
            GridLines="Vertical" Style="left: 121px; position: absolute; top: 133px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckAll" runat="server" onclick="return check_uncheck (this );" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="ID" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "FedTaxID") %>'
                            Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="checkRec" runat="server" onclick="return check_uncheck (this );" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FedTaxID" SortExpression="FedTaxID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFedTaxID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FedTaxID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFedTaxID1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FedTaxID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EntryDescription" HeaderText="CompanyEntryDescription"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BankRoutingNumber" HeaderText="RoutingNumber"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount"></asp:BoundField>
```

> This is from another table

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TaxAuthority" SortExpression="Taxing_Auth_Name">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTaxAuthority" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Taxing_Auth_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTaxAuthority" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Taxing_Auth_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


            </Columns>
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

But i am getting an error as `DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Taxing_Auth_Name'.`

So can any one tell what to do

My stored proc that executes for binding

```
  select c.fedtaxid,companyname,'comapany desc',c.entrydescription,
  c.BankRoutingNumber,
  g.Amount,g.TaxAuthority from tblcustomer c join (
  select swc.fedtaxid As FedTaxID,sum(amount)  Amount, taxing_auth_name TaxAuthority from tbl_employees_swc_grosswagedetails swc where wage_code='GRTT' and    taxing_auth_name='FED' and (empid,payperiodnumber,payyear)  in (select distinct  empid,PayPeriodID,payyear  from tblcpyresults cpyr where  cpyr.fedtaxid=swc.fedtaxid )   group by swc.fedtaxid) g on c.fedtaxid=g.fedtaxid;
```

Comment: Instead, of these. Its better to add all the Columns in grid at once you want at aspx page, then later in the code behind append the extra columns from another table to the Dataset which you are giving to the datagrid.

Comment: @Kalyan : through code i had written this but i would like to know whether it is possible or not

Comment: This may happens due to the mismatch of columns that you are calling from your code can you post the code that u have written to bind the gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your store procedure you written this

```
 taxing_auth_name TaxAuthority
```

So define your label with `TaxAuthority` this will resolve the issue..

Like follows

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TaxAuthority" SortExpression="TaxAuthority">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTaxAuthority" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TaxAuthority") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTaxAuthority" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TaxAuthority") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```